# Dynamically creating a navbar

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm creating a string that is an unordered list, and I'd like to replace my navbar.

But I lose my formatting when I say:

```
$(':jqmData(role=navbar)').html(str).trigger("create");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

does this work?

```
$(':jqmData(role=navbar)').html(str).navbar();
```

Comment: I was able to do it by removing the <nav data-role="navbar"> altogether and then reinserting it again with a $('header').trigger('create');

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a little late but it worked for me. Try doing the .trigger('create') on the parent of the navbar element

Comment: Never too late @thedjaney. I'll try that solution the next time I'm in the hood.